# Category shown in list-view

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

is there a way to setup categories in a way that `Category1` is only shown when there are no other categories selected.

Currently it shows the category which has been selected first.

`Category1` + `Category2` shows `Category1`
`Category2` + `Category1` shows `Category2`

Thanks

EDIT:
Typo3 Version: 7.6.23
News Version: 6.1.1

Comment: please add the versions you are using (TYPO3, ext:news)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ sorry. added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anaylyzing the news template `ext:news/resources/Private/Partials/List/Item.html` you will find this fluid code:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.firstCategory}">
    <!-- first category -->
    <span class="news-list-category">{newsItem.firstCategory.title}</span>
</f:if>
```

Which will only show one category (probably the first one)

if you want all categories have a look into the detail-view (`ext:news/Resources/Private/templates/News/Detail.html`):

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.categories}">
    <f:render partial="Category/Items" arguments="{categories:newsItem.categories, settings:settings}" />
</f:if>
```

copy the item partial from list view into your space (extensions) and modify the category inclusion by replacing it from the detail view.
Additionally you can add a logic to skip the `Category1`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. We used a workaround. Setting the module to show any category within the parent-category and removed the unwanted category from all posts. I dont know why the person who set up that page set it up the way he did.